# Steam install in wine not working

Tags: wine, games, steam

I know this isn't an Ubuntu specific problem but I am hoping I might find some help here from the Ubuntu Community who may have experienced this issue before.

I know its possible to run steam natively but I have recently made the complete switch to Ubuntu and would like to run steam under wine so I can install and play my windows games.

I am currently using crossover but had the same problem with PlayOnLinux and manually using wine.

Steam installs fine and I get to the Login screen, I enter my details and proceed to enter the code that you receive in an email from Steam, and then it just disappears and when you open Steam again you are brought back to the login screen and have to repeat the process.

If anyone has any information on this it would be greatly appreciated.

I hope this is not too general, I have tried this on my laptop and desktop and had the same effect. I searched online and found no information about this specific problem.

Comment: If you are using Crossover, one of the perks is that you can get support on officially supported programs, and I'm pretty sure that Steam is one of those.  Just use the "ticket" system to fill out a ticket.  They are good about getting back to you and work hard to get your issue solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try searching winehq about steam?

take it from me, whenever you install anything on wine always search google to find out if wine needs additional components to run the program. *especially if it's a game*!

...here's what I have for you https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444

scroll down to the "how-to-install" part. it *might* fix your problem. ... I hope

: )